# Can't boot into Ubuntu from CD, or from Acronis True Image recovery disk

Tags: ubuntu, bootable-media, acronis-trueimage

I can boot my computer off a home-burned-from-ISO-image Windows 7 (x64 or x86) installation CD, without problems.  It's a Quad 6600, 4GB RAM, 8800GT and most of the time runs Win7 with no problems.

However, if I boot off a CD containing Ubuntu (10.04 or 9.something IIRC), or a recovery disk created with Acronis True Image Home 2010, it:

- boots
- starts to load the OS from the CD
- then hangs
- ... and I have to reset.

I've tried all these CDs on another computer, and they boot up into Ubuntu or Acronis respectively with no problems at all.

Any ideas what to look for?

Sorry this is a little vague but I have no idea where to start, really ... if there's more information needed I'll edit the question.

TIA!

Comment: it might be having a problem identifying the processor or other hardware...you might have to look at custom boot options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the solution, quite by accident.

If I hold the `Ctrl` key down as it boots off the CD, I get the boot menu (including the 'try ubuntu without making any changes' option for running it off the CD), and I can then select options and boot into Ubuntu normally.

Strangely, if I insert the Acronis recovery disk, this now also boots up into the True Image application (without needing to hold the `Ctrl` key down, I might add), and behaves normally.

I'm completely mystified as to how the one might affect the other across reboots.  If anyone knows why this might be the case, I'd like to know.

Comment: I suspect coincidence is involved in the Acronis disk now working.  Perhaps there is a transient hardware flaw.  I would say you should try a memory tester, just because that's easy.

Answer (score 0):

Boot problems can be caused by many things. I would suggest that you search for a forum related to the problem. One way is to search Bing or Google for "boot problems" and look for hits that point to forums. On a forum, people can ask you for more specific information in order to narrow down the search for the cause of your specific problem. Also check the sites of your software and hardware manufacturers for their  troubleshooting guides (usually found on the Support page). I think these approaches are more appropriate for troubleshooting specific computer problems, as they are better set up for back&forth conversations and are usually system or product oriented. I'm new to this place and others may disagree, so don't give up yet on getting an answer here. Good luck.